# Jquery selectable for range selection (slider behaviour)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to replace a slider with a list of values and an option to select the range. I followed the jquery selectable article, which provides a nice multi-select option

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid

Since I only want range selection, I disabled the the Ctrl-click using the below code.

```
  $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
            e.metaKey = false;
            }).selectable();
```

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disabling-ctrl-click-on-jquery-ui-selectable

This disables ctrl-select, but I can still drag the mouse and select values that are not in the range.

My list is laid out as a 4x4 matrix. Problem is I can drag my mouse and choose values in the same columns, which do not highlight the values in the adjacent columns under the same range. Is there any way out other than a single row?

Comment: Can you show us a demo page for that? Because, for me, the description of what is going on is a bit blurry.

Comment: I will try to put a page in sometime.In short I want to click and drag the selectable list like a range selector. The existing functionality works fine if you have a single row but with multiple rows (matrix) there is a issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a function that creates a selectable from a namevalue collection. I am new to Jquery and Javascript so there is room for some fine tuning.

```
function NameValue(name, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    function createRangeSelectable(elementName, nameValueCollection, functionReference) {
           var newElementId = "selectable" + elementName;
        var orderedListHTML = "<ol id='" + newElementId + "' class='selectable'>";
        var itemHTML = "";

        for (x in nameValueCollection) {
            var item = nameValueCollection[x];
            itemHTML = itemHTML + "<li class='ui-state-default'>" + item.name + "<input type='hidden' value='" + item.value + "'/></li>";
        }

        orderedListHTML = orderedListHTML + itemHTML + "</ol>"

        $("#" + elementName).html(orderedListHTML);


        $("#" + newElementId).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
            e.metaKey = false;
        }).selectable({

            stop: function () {
                var first = -1;
                var last = -1;

                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {

                    var index = $("li", this.parentElement).index(this);
                    if (first == -1)
                        first = index
                    last = index
                });

                var firstListItemValue;
                var lastListItemValue;

                $("li", this).each(function () {


                    var index = $("li", this.parentElement).index(this);
                    if (index == first) {
                        firstListItemValue = $(this).children('input').val();
                    }
                    if (index == last)
                        lastListItemValue = $(this).children('input').val();

                    if (index > first && index < last)
                        if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-selected"))
                            $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
                });

                functionReference(firstListItemValue, lastListItemValue);
            }

        });

//Usage

createRangeSelectable("YourDivId", NameValueArray, function(startValue, endValue){

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rows and want each separate row to be a subject of drag-selecting, simply make `.selectable()` on each row. I put up a demo for this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Nm69t/ (or separate page view: http://jsfiddle.net/Nm69t/show)

You can see, that I've created three lists (working as three separate rows) and made each of the row selectable by doing `$('.selectable').selectable();`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope that wont work for me. It should be a single range list. I can choose a range from 1 row to n rows.

Comment: So I don't get it, really. You got a 4x4 matrix. Do you want to get rid of functionality where you can drag to select multiple items? Or do you want to be able to drag-select, for example, third column and you want all items from the left up to that column to be selected?

Comment: I want the later. Click an element and drag all the way to select the entire range. So I click the cell (1R,1C) and drag vertically to cell (2R, 1C), it should select all in the range (1R,2C) (1R,3C), (1R, 4C)

Comment: Aaaah, now I get it :D It can be done. I guess by handling event that is fired once the selection stops and than manually calculating and selecting cells that suppose to be selected. I'll try to put up a working example.

Comment: I'm halfway there http://jsfiddle.net/Nm69t/2/ the only thing left to do is to get rid of default selection that is being set after release of a mouse button. To be honest it would be much easier to get rid of jQuery selectable all together since I pretty much mocked the selecting function anyway.

Comment: Looks good. I have implemented something similar. Posting it as an answer. Its dirty but working for me

Answer (score 0):

I put up a demo for this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/snyuan/TGekT/, and http://jsfiddle.net/snyuan/Yrgnv/. Just a reference.

Comment: This is more of a comment, unless you expand on the links